# Why doesn't monkeyrunner find my python module?

Tags: android, python, jython, monkeyrunner

**The problem:**

```
ImportError: No module named progress
```

**The python code:**

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from progress.bar import Bar

print "Starting the script..."

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(deviceId='FA489WM01202')

y = 500
x2 = 500
pause = 0.02
bar = Bar('Processing', max=40000)

for i in range(40000):
    device.touch(x2, y, 'DOWN_AND_UP')
    MonkeyRunner.sleep(pause)
    bar.next()

bar.finish()

print "Finished the script..."
```

**My PATH variables:**

- PATH ->
  [....];C:\jython2.7.0\bin;C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages;D:\android\adt-bundle\sdk;D:\android\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;D:\android\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools
- ANDROID_HOME -> D:\android\adt-bundle\sdk
- JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
- JYTHON_HOME -> C:\jython2.7.0
- JYTHONPATH -> C:\jython2.7.0\Lib
- PYTHON_HOME -> C:\Python34
- PYTHONPATH -> C:\Python34\Lib

**What I tried so far:**

- installed the progress module via cmd "python -m pip progress install"
- installed the progress module via cmd "python setup.py install"
- installed the progress module via cmd "easy_install progress"

The module was installed successfully every time and also listed in either the `site-packages` folder or the `vendor` folder of `pip`, but it's still not working.
Even after I put the module files in the same directory as the scripts location it won't work... I'm out of ideas at the moment...

Comment: Perhaps [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) solves your problem.

Comment: @dtmilano Thanks for your suggestion, sounds interesting. I'll test it.